# How to do this query in NHibernate 3?

Tags: nhibernate, crosstab

I have 4 tables and every one has a field named `FormulaToken (nvarchar(250))`.

When user enters new value in `FormulaToken` in any of the entity (connected to one of these 4 tables), I need to check that this value is unique across all 4 tables.

How to do this?

Comment: Let say this, I have 4 tables, Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, each one mapped to its entity class with the same name.

Comment: Some code and mappings demonstrating what you're trying to accomplish would help us in understanding your intent and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Instead of checking all 4 tables for the value of one field, I excracted this field to its own table and set it to unique indexed.